# rbenv install 2.6.1 FAILED on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operating-system

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to download ruby 2.6.1 on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3 but I keep getting failed builds and I'm not sure what the error is.

Please help! Completely lost :(

**Current setup:** .

```
> rbenv install --version
ruby-build 20190130
> llvm-gcc --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)     
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0     
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

**ATTEMPTED FIXES**

I've tried unsetting RUBY_CFLAGS, deleting/ redownloading command line tools/ rbenv/rvm, changing my developer directory to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools. Really not sure where to go from here.

---

**CODE**

I've tried both

```
rbenv install 2.6.1
```

and

```
CC=gcc rbenv install 2.6.1
```

---

**RESULTS**

Expected result: `ruby build successful.`
Actual result:

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.3 using ruby-build 20190130)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/0k/yx4v818d37v50bw7xmr8bvlh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190210231226.58235
Results logged to /var/folders/0k/yx4v818d37v50bw7xmr8bvlh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190210231226.58235.log
Last 10 log lines:
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h
```

---

**Ruby Build Log from Config Summary onwards:**

```
   Configuration summary for ruby version 2.6.1

   * Installation prefix: /Users/michelleslee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1
   * exec prefix:         ${prefix}
   * arch:                x86_64-darwin18
   * site arch:           ${arch}
   * RUBY_BASE_NAME:      ruby
   * ruby lib prefix:     ${libdir}/${RUBY_BASE_NAME}
   * site libraries path: ${rubylibprefix}/${sitearch}
   * vendor path:         ${rubylibprefix}/vendor_ruby
   * target OS:           darwin18
   * compiler:            $(CC_WRAPPER) gcc
   * with pthread:        yes
   * enable shared libs:  no
   * dynamic library ext: bundle
   * CFLAGS:              ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}
   * LDFLAGS:             -L. \
                          -L/Users/michelleslee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib \
                          -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names \
                          -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -fstack-protector-strong \
                          -L/usr/local/lib
   * DLDFLAGS:            -L/Users/michelleslee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib \
                          -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names \
                          -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs \
                          -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup \
                          -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress
   * optflags:            -O3
   * debugflags:          -ggdb3
   * warnflags:           -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement \
                          -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero \
                          -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int \
                          -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 \
                          -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn \
                          -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long \
                          -Wno-missing-field-initializers \
                          -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality \
                          -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare \
                          -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value \
                          -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens
   * strip command:       /anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip -A \
                          -n
   * install doc:         yes
   * JIT support:         yes
   * man page type:       doc

---
    BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = ./tool/darwin-cc gcc
    LD = /anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld
    LDSHARED = ./tool/darwin-cc gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe  
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
    CPPFLAGS = -I/Users/michelleslee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/11.0.0 
    DLDFLAGS = -L/Users/michelleslee/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-pie -framework Security -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = 
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling load.c
compiling marshal.c
file.c:2679:6: warning: 'utimensat' is only available on macOS 10.13 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
        if (utimensat(AT_FDCWD, path, tsp, flags) < 0) {
            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:374:5: note: 'utimensat' has been explicitly marked partial here
int     utimensat(int __fd, const char *__path, const struct timespec __times[2],
        ^
file.c:2679:6: note: enclose 'utimensat' in a __builtin_available check to silence this warning
        if (utimensat(AT_FDCWD, path, tsp, flags) < 0) {
            ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling math.c
making mjit_config.h
compiling mjit_compile.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling proc.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling thread.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling transient_heap.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling vm_trace.c
compiling ./missing/explicit_bzero.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling addr2line.c
compiling dmyenc.c
compiling dln.c
compiling localeinit.c
compiling prelude.c
config.status: creating ruby-runner.h
compiling array.c
compiling mjit.c
assembling coroutine/amd64/Context.S
compiling enc/ascii.c
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
compiling version.c
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
generating encdb.h
building .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/transform_mjit_header.rb "./tool/darwin-cc gcc " rb_mjit_header.h .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h
encdb.h updated
./tool/ifchange "--timestamp=.rbconfig.time" rbconfig.rb rbconfig.tmp
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
creating verconf.h
verconf.h updated
compiling loadpath.c
making srcs under enc
linking static-library libruby.2.6-static.a
/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar: illegal option -- n
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make: *** [Makefile:286: libruby.2.6-static.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Entering directory '/private/var/folders/0k/yx4v818d37v50bw7xmr8bvlh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190210231226.58235/ruby-2.6.1'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'srcs'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/0k/yx4v818d37v50bw7xmr8bvlh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190210231226.58235/ruby-2.6.1'

Transforming external functions to static:
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aset' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_equal_opt' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_vm_search_method_slowpath' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_push_frame' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cref_new_toplevel' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sigbits
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospi
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospif
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincos
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincosf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormall
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormald
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormalf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h
```

Comment: You could try updating are reinstalling rbenv

Comment: @PaulByrne, tried that but got the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error which prevents the build from successful finish is:

```
/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar: illegal option -- n
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
```

So you are using the acanconda's archiver instead of the macOS provided one. In order to fix this you need to switch to the macOS provided compilation tools.

You can do this by removing acanconda from your `PATH` and reload your terminal.

I'm not sure about the exact steps, but I think this should work:

- Go to your `/home/<user>/.bashrc` file, remove anaconda from the PATH, save the file
- Reload your terminal (by restarting it or executing`source ~/.bashrc`)
- `rbenv install 2.1.6`

The goal is not to have any anaconda related tools in Ruby build log, but the system provided tools.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I removed the anaconda path from my .bash_profile and everything worked perfectly!!!

Been banging my head for two days, can't thank you enough!

Comment: Works :) I do not use rbenv but ruby-install and it has helped too.

Answer (score -1):

Because I had the same BUILD RESULT (exact same 10 last lines in the log), I ended up here, hence this post.

In my case (therefore, different issue, same symptom), I had forgotten to upgrade my MacPort when I switched to Mojave. Migration procedure for MacPort is described here :  https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
(takes a while).

my two cents

Comment: As you say, this doesn't address the problem here.